# How to escape regexp special characters in a string?

Tags: regular-expressions

I'm composing a complex regular expression and the user can supply a part of the expression.  However, the user-supplied part should be interpreted literally, i.e. regexp special characters should be escaped.  Is there a function for escaping these characters?  It seems like a common thing to do but all my googling was unsuccessful.

Example:

```
(re-search-forward (format "\b%s\b" user-string))
```

If `user-string` is `test*case`, I want to match `test*case` but not `testttttcase`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`regexp-quote`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Functions.html):

> This function returns a regular expression whose only exact match is string. Using this regular expression in looking-at will succeed only if the next characters in the buffer are string; using it in a search function will succeed if the text being searched contains string.

`(regexp-quote "^The cat$") => \\^The cat\\$`

Comment: Great, thanks! But why was this so difficult to find?  Sometimes Emacs' documentation drives me crazy.

Comment: You can describe what you looked for, and where you expected to find about this function, with M-x report-emacs-bug. Perhaps the documentation is lacking and should be fixed.

Comment: @tmalsburg A useful keyword would be "escape".  Perhaps `(defalias 'regexp-escape 'regexp-quote)`.  Was this discussed on any of the emacs mailing lists?